# How to write raw audio data to a file captured using Alsa Driver C++

Tags: c++, audio, alsa, raw-data

I'm trying to write raw audio data to a specific file, using Alsa Driver.

Below the code:

```
ofstream binaryFile ("file.raw", ios::out | ios::binary);

if(inputData==NULL)
{
    inputData = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeOfDataInBytes);
}

while (audio_en)
{
    snd_pcm_sframes_t numAudioFramesRead = snd_pcm_readi(ndi_AudioSupport.m_captureHandle,inputData, 
    ndi_AudioSupport.m_numAudioFramesPerVideoFrame);
    
    if(numAudioFramesRead > 0)
    {
        binaryFile.write ((char*)inputData, sizeof (inputData));
    }
}

binaryFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to write many different audio formats including raw is to use the sox audio library (libsox). C++ ALSA classes and libsox classes are built into gtkIOStream.

An example for capturing to a raw audio file comes from the [ALSACapture.C source code here](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/applications/ALSACapture.C#L78). The basic concept is to open the capture device and the raw audio file, then loop through capturing audio and writing to file using Sox :

```
  Capture capture("default"); // open the default ALSA capture device
  Sox<int> sox;
  int ret=sox.openWrite("audio.raw", fs, capture.getChannels(), pow(2.,(double)snd_pcm_format_width(format)));
  while (continue){
    capture>>buffer;
    sox.write(buffer);
  }
```

The nice thing about using libsox is that you aren't limited to the raw audio format.